# With Twig and WordPress, how do I determine if a post is in a category?

Tags: wordpress, twig

Twig newbie here :)  And I'm using WordPress.

In a .twig file, I can display the category.slug this way:

```
{% for category in post.terms('category') %}
    {{ category.slug }}
{% endfor %}
```

But how do I use an `if` construct with the `category.slug`?

I.e., I want to display the category if the post is in the category in-the-news. This obviously doesn't work:

```
{% for category in post.terms('category') %}

   {% if category.slug == in-the-news %}

      In The News

   {% else %}

      Other Category

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This is twig version is 1.34. Fiddle here from Matteo: https://twigfiddle.com/89t9gr

Comment: Is not clear for me what do not works https://twigfiddle.com/89t9gr

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why the fiddle works with my example; `{% for category in categories %} {{ category.slug }} {% endfor %}` does not work for me in my Twig install. My twig version is 1.34.

Comment: Version does not matter. You can switch to `Twig 1.34` on `TwigFiddle` and it still works. Are u getting any error? Also you are enquoting `in-the-news` right?

Comment: very strange, what error you have? Can you share the error message?

Comment: Thanks, DarkBee and Matteo, no errors that I could see, but the problem seems to have been no quotes around the category slugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. I think the issue in my localhost and Twig v1.34 was having no quotes around the category slugs. And, for me, `{% for category in categories %}` does not work and does not throw an error.

```
{% for category in post.terms('category') %}

     {% if category.slug == "in-the-news" %}

     In The News

     {% elseif category.slug == "videos" %}

     Video

     {% else %}

     All Else

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```